# upper-bound intersecting unnecessarily

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I was going through basics of [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation.

> f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means c.g(n) is a lower bound on f(n) such that f(n) is always ≥ c.g(n)
>
> f(n) = O(g(n)) means c.g(n) is an upper bound on f(n) such that f(n) is always 
>   ≤ c.g(n)
>       for all n ≥ n0

[image]

upper and lower bound is clear in graph above, **but why is f(n) and upperbound intersecting? when its clear from above definition?** does that have meaning or I am just pointing out unnecessarily?

*Source: The Algorith Design Manual by Skiena*

Comment: Behavior of f(n) in this context is asymptotic, that is it is true "for large enough n" (as written in the caption of the figure you put)

Comment: statement holds for all n > n0 (as depicted in your figure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the first two definitions, there should not be an intersection because of the word **always**

> f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means c.g(n) is a lower bound on f(n) such that f(n) is
>   always ≥ c.g(n)
>
> f(n) = O(g(n)) means c.g(n) is an upper bound on f(n) such that f(n)
>   is always ≤ c.g(n)

**These definitions are not exactly correct**. Because the idea for big-O notation is to check the number of operations when `n` is really big. In layman terms it means that you start checking the complexity only after some number which you consider big enough. This is outlined on your picture:

> Upper and lower bounds valid for n > n0 ...

and this is why on the picture you have a vertical line n0. So you do not care about anything before this line, because you consider only numbers after n0 big enough.

To make these definitions exactly correct, just add for n > n0 at the end of both of them.

Comment: so generally the highlight here should be on n>n0? coz we are concerned with scale?

Comment: @brykneval I would not say that you have to highlight `n > n0` because the first part is more important. But you have to remember that when you speak about big-O you are concerned about very big numbers, so you do not care about some elements before big numbers. This is exactly why part `n > n0` is important.

Comment: so my general assumption was someone taller to me will always be taller whether its measured in inch, or cm or meter. but I got your point i.e. it holds only for n>n0, coz there is a constant that can be 0.1 too

Comment: @brykneval - doesn't seem to me like you understood this really. The idea is that for small enough *N* the property might not hold. Consider a standard binary search - that's well known to be *O(log(N))*, but if you binary search for 4 in [1, 5, 10] you'd have 2 failed comparison operators, whereas *log2(3)* ~= 1.5. As the array grows, eventual it will hold true for all sizes...

Answer (score 2):

The definition is simply inaccurate. Big-O notation is about asymptotic growth. As such, it's properties are considered for "large enough *N*", which means it might not hold true for small *N*'s.

In the chart, a "large enough *N*" is marked as *N0*, after which the limiting property is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been already said in other answers, the inequalities in the definition are incorrect as well, they should be reversed:

> f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means c.g(n) is a lower bound on f(n) such that f(n) is always ≥ c.g(n)
>
> f(n) = O(g(n)) means c.g(n) is an upper bound on f(n) such that f(n) is always ≤ c.g(n)